# How can I know whether current mode is design mode or not in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have 3rd-party's animation QML Component but, it doesn't show in the QML Designer.

I think it's not possible to play the animation in the designer but
I hope to show a still image instead.

Is there any way to know current mode is design-mode or not in QML?

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible to check this from within a QML component?

Comment: that's right. sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to, from within a QML component, check if Qt Quick Designer is in design mode. QML components shouldn't know anything about Qt Quick Designer. I'm not sure how Qt Quick Designer renders items on "forms", and I can't manage to find this out from brief Googling. I'd suggest that you ask this on the [Qt Creator Mailing List](http://lists.qt-project.org/mailman/listinfo/qt-creator).

Answer (score 2):

There is private API in QtDeclarative that allows you to check if you are running in the designer: QQmlEnginePrivate::designerMode().

QQmlEnginePrivate::designerMode() is just a static method which you can call from C++. You need to include  and add qml-private to your .pro file.

Just keep in mind that the usual API guarantees do not hold for private API. In theory such private API can change with any Qt version.

Comment: Is there any way to call the method from QML? or Qt?